# A single query to count the number of distinct rows in one table and the highest value of a column from another table

Tags: sql, join, db2, aggregate-functions

I have two SQL tables. Table 1 is as follows:

```
     SALEREF
 1 | 40303020
 2 | 40303021
 3 | 40303021
 4 | 40303021
 5 | 41210028  
 6 | 4120302701
 7 | 41210030  
 8 | 4112700803
 9 | 4112700803
10 | 41215030  
11 | 41215026  
12 | 41215026  
13 | 41215026  
14 | 41215026  
15 | 41215026  
16 | 41215026  
17 | 41215026  
18 | 41215027  
19 | 41215027  
20 | 41215027
```

Table 2 ("LEDGER") is as follows:

```
     SALESREF       SALEDATE  
 0 | 4081200201  |  20140804 
 1 | 40303020    |  20141015 
 2 | 40303021    |  20141017 
 3 | 40303021    |  20141017 
 4 | 40303021    |  20141017 
 5 | 41210028    |  20121214 
 6 | 4120302701  |  20130926 
 7 | 41210030    |  20130926 
 8 | 4112700803  |  20131107 
 9 | 4112700803  |  20131107 
10 | 41215030    |  20120720
```

What I am looking for is a single line that outputs the following:

```
 TotalDistinctSalesRefsInTable1   HighestSaleDateValueInTable2 (that has a matching value in table 1)
            9                      20141017
```

the total number of distinct SALESREF's in table 1 and the latest SALESDATE value from table 2.

I've tried selecting within a query but quickly found the limitation of my knowledge although I know I can get the latest overall sale date by doing:

```
SELECT MAX(LEDGER.SALEDATE) AS LAST_DATE FROM LEDGER
```

I just need help piecing the whole thing together.

Comment: And why do you need this in a single query?

Comment: I just think it is cleaner....I'm using ibatis and two queries would means the overhead of an additional resultset and method

Comment: @mustaccio The query is taking 0.6 secs which is slightly worrying. Do you think I'd get a performance boost from two queries ?

Comment: Now that you have the alternative, you tell me. Consider also testing with realistic volumes of data -- I'd assume a ledger to contain a bit more than just 20 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `left join` , `count` and `max` to get your desired result

```
select count(distinct t1.salesref) as TotalDistinctSalesRefsInTable1,
       ifnull(max(l.saledate),0) as HighestSaleDateValueInTable
from table1 t1
left join ledger l
on t1.salesref = l.salesref
```

Comment: IFNULL does seem to work in its place. Any chance you could update your answer ?